# Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm Django Create View User

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using a create view to make users in the system but the admin keeps saying that there is an "Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm." for the user? I'm using the UserCreationForm provided by the framework

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserCreate(CreateView):
    model = User
    form = UserCreationForm
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password')
    template_name = 'exts/user_create.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        # login the person
        self.object.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
        auth_login(self.request, self.object)
        # now return the success url
        return '/'

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(CreateView, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['password'].widget = forms.PasswordInput()
        return form
```

Answer (score 2):

While using the Django's default User model, the password is encrypted before storing. Hence, you cannot simply set the password of a User like the other fields. You should override your save method to set password using the `set_password('MyPassword')` method of User model

Comment: does the createview have a save method? Its not showing up in pycharm for me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `form_class` rather than `form` to specify the form class to use.

You also have `password` in your fields, but the `UserCreationForm` does not specify a `password` field. Since it's a valid field on the model, the form field is automatically generated, but does not set the password correctly.

You should add the `password1` and `password2` fields instead:

```
class UserCreate(CreateView):
    model = User
    form = UserCreationForm
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2')
    ...
```

Comment: `FieldError at /createaccount
Unknown field(s) (password2, password1) specified for User` when I do that

Comment: @GrantPowell Right, I missed that you're using `form` instead of `form_class`.

Comment: hmmm its saying that you can't use `form_class` and `fields` at the same time, but I got it to work in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! turns out you want to use the form class attribute instead of the form and model attributes, works perfectly now!

```
class UserCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    template_name = 'exts/user_create.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def get_success_url(self):
        # login the person
        self.object.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
        auth_login(self.request, self.object)
        # now return the success url
        return '/'
```